# Using AsyncTask with BufferedReader to get line in a http

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use `AsyncTask` and `BufferedReader` to read the line shown in the http with the following code.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String request_url = "http://www.ryanheise.com/sarcastic.cgi";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(request_url);
            try {
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                try {
                    String joke = in.readLine();
                    Log.d("Joke -- ", joke);
                    return joke;
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("IOE", " ----------- IOE");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("MURL", " ----------- MURL");
        }

        return "unable to get joke";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mJoke_tv.setText(result);
        Log.d("onPost", result);
    }
}
```

and it runs with no exception but returns an unexpected result.
the log.d("joke---" , joke) shows:

```
"!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">"
```

which I have no idea why.

the logcat shows:

```
D/Joke --: !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

can anyone help me out of it please?
many thanks.

Comment: The first line of the HTML of the page you are reading is obviously going to indicate the Doctype of the html document. You need to parse the html to eventually find the text of the joke.

Comment: You say you got an unexpected result.  What exactly were you expecting??

Comment: did you make it work @Jamen?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque yep.sorry for replying so late, the reason is that the url should be https://blabla, and i put http instead.